# remove rows in bash based on values

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a file like this:

```
1 4014 1.97676  1   1
1 4014 1.97676  2   1
1 4014 1.97676  3   1
1 2014 1.97676  4   1
1 2014 1.97676  5   1
1 401 1.97676  6   1
1 401 1.97676  7   1
1 401 1.97676  8   1
1 14 1.97676  9   1
1 14 1.97676  10  1
```

I want to trim this file: Remove rows with values in the 2nd column < 1000. After trimming, the file should look like this:

```
1 4014 1.97676  1   1
1 4014 1.97676  2   1
1 4014 1.97676  3   1
1 2014 1.97676  4   1
1 2014 1.97676  5   1
```

How to achieve this in bash? I don't want to do it in python especially in pandas because they are slow dealing with large files.

Another question is: how can I write such bash commands in a .sh file (similar to .py file run by python) and run the file in terminal like this:

```
$bash clean_file.sh inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

Thank you very much.

---

---

Here's what I want to do:

The file is like this:

```
NODE_1_length_4014_cov_1.97676  1   1
NODE_1_length_4014_cov_1.97676  2   1
NODE_1_length_4014_cov_1.97676  3   1
NODE_1_length_4014_cov_1.97676  4   1
NODE_1_length_4014_cov_1.97676  5   1
NODE_1_length_4014_cov_1.97676  6   1
NODE_1_length_4014_cov_1.97676  7   1
NODE_1_length_4014_cov_1.97676  8   1
NODE_1_length_4014_cov_1.97676  9   1
NODE_1_length_4014_cov_1.97676  10  1
```

I'd like to clean it using the following steps:

```
#First, split the first column by the delimiter '_' and only keep the numbers:
awk -F '_' -v OFS='\t' '{print $2,$4,$6,$7,$8}' 
#Second, remove the last two empty columns, because, after the first step, it generates two extra invisible columns, which need to be removed.
cut -f 1-5 
#remove rows with values in the 2nd column less than 500
awk '$2 >= 500 { print }'
```

I didn't add 'inputfile' and 'outputfile' in the scripts above, because each step uses previous step's outputfile as the input file. I don't know how to combine the three steps in one script file and save it in the hard drive. I want to run it in terminal for files stored at different locations in my computer.

Thank you very much!

Comment: `remove the last two empty columns` you don't need that step... the awk solution should have been `awk -F '_' -v OFS='\t' '{print $2,$4,$6}'`

Comment: to combine it with new requirement, use `awk -F '_' -v OFS='\t' '$2 >= 500 {print $2,$4,$6}'` on original file.. just one single command, no need scripting

Comment: That's very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

bash is the wrong tool.

```
awk '$2 >= 1000 { print }'
```

Comment: you can remove `{ print }`

Comment: Thank you very much. How to make this script in a file and run it in terminal? Can I add  a series of 'awk' and 'cut' commands in one file and run it in terminal so that it will do the same job to a number of files?

Comment: Dump it into a script file, give it the input in stdin, and the output will be in stdout.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, can you explain how to do this? I really know very little about this.

Comment: `sh somescript.sh < inputfile > outputfile`

Comment: Thank you very much. I need to clean my file with three steps, like this: 1)
awk -F '_' -v OFS='\t' '{print $2,$4,$6,$7,$8}' reads_contig.coverage > reads_contig_clean.coverage 
2) cut -f 1-5 reads_contig_clean.coverage > reads_contig_short.coverage
3) awk '$2 >= 500' reads_contig_short.coverage > reads_contig_short500.coverage     How to combine them in one script and run it one time to do the job?

Comment: @SteveXu, if you could do let us know what should be done apart from you mentioned  in your post, could write it in a single command for you, but you have to let us know complete details on same.,

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Thank you for your help. I edited my question with details of what I want to achieve. Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Such filtering is indeed trivial with `awk`, but just for completeness (education), here's a `bash`-only version:

```
#!/bin/bash

# "parse"/validate a script's argument (filename)
if [[ ! -e "$1" ]]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 FILE"
    exit
fi

# iterate over lines, splitting into fields on whitespaces
while read -ra fields; do
    (( fields[1] >= 1000 )) && echo "${fields[@]}"
done <"$1"
```

The usage is like:

```
$ ./clean_file.sh inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

your second sample input file doesn't have any test condition.  So I updated with

```
$ sed -i '5,$s/4014/300/' file
```

and it became

```
NODE_1_length_4014_cov_1.97676  1   1
NODE_1_length_4014_cov_1.97676  2   1
NODE_1_length_4014_cov_1.97676  3   1
NODE_1_length_4014_cov_1.97676  4   1
NODE_1_length_300_cov_1.97676  5   1
NODE_1_length_300_cov_1.97676  6   1
NODE_1_length_300_cov_1.97676  7   1
NODE_1_length_300_cov_1.97676  8   1
NODE_1_length_300_cov_1.97676  9   1
NODE_1_length_300_cov_1.97676  10  1
```

you want to remove the entries with length less than 500.  This simple `awk` script will do!

```
$ awk '{split($1,f1,"_")} f1[4]>=500' file

NODE_1_length_4014_cov_1.97676  1   1
NODE_1_length_4014_cov_1.97676  2   1
NODE_1_length_4014_cov_1.97676  3   1
NODE_1_length_4014_cov_1.97676  4   1
```